# $a_n\leq b_n$, then $a\leq b.$ Is the converse true?

Tags: real-analysis

Sequences:
If $b_n$ converges to b, $a_n$ converges to a, and $b_n \geq a_n, \forall n$ then $b\geq a$.

Firstly, I have some questions about this proof. Is this okay? I mean I'm confused, I had to bring the = sign in by myself in the inequalities just so I could get $b_n \geq a_n$. I'd appreciate if someone can guide me to the right path and show me how a proper proof should be written/how it works. I know questions like these have been posted before, I looked at every one of them, tried to understand and picked the solution that is simplest for me. I just started real analysis.

(I studied definition of limit of a sequence all by myself, apologies if this proof is wrong).

By definition of limit of a sequence:

$| b_n - b | < E \\
b - E \leq bn \leq b + E \\
| a_n - a | < E \\
a - E \leq an \leq a + E \\
bn \geq an \implies a - E \leq an \leq bn \leq b + E \\
a - E \leq b + E \\
a \leq b + 2E, \forall E > 0 \\
2E = c \\
a \leq b + c, \forall c > 0 \\
a \leq b$

E is meant to be epsilon and I've already gone through the proof of the last inequality $a\leq b + c,  \forall c > 0 \implies a\leq b$ so I just used the result directly.

Another question I have is, "Is the converse true"?

Ie: If $b \geq a$, then $b_n \geq a_n, \forall n$.

Comment: Use `$\varepsilon$`, i.e., $\varepsilon$ to typeset epsilon.

Comment: Let $x_n = b_b-a_n$. If $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \ge 0$ is $x \ge 0$? Note that the set $[0,\infty)$ is closed.

Comment: The converse is not true:  if $a_n=1+\frac 1n$ and $b_n=1-\frac 1n$ then $a_n>b_n\,\forall n$ but $a=b=1$.  If you want an exercise, try to prove:  "If $b>a$ then $b_n>a_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$". which is at least a partial converse.

Comment: Another reason the converse isn't true is that $a_n, b_n$ aren't given to be monotone. So you could have oscillating sequences that pass each other many times on their way to a limit.

Comment: There are plenty of counterexamples, almost everything that you can write down will work. Are you sure that you even tried the question?

Comment: @Sonny, the converse is _so obviously_ not true that I wonder why you even asked the question.

Comment: I am not fond of the last part of your proof, when you deal with $a \le b +2E$. Personally, I would have supposed that $a>b$ and then find an $E$ contradicting this.

Comment: My opinion is that he is thinking about the converse as something that would be true for $n$ sufficiently large. I agree this is not the "exact" converse anyway. @TonyK

Comment: I did not know that the converse is so obviously not true, I'm reading all the comments and trying to understand everything. Btw @nicomezi thanks I'll try your method for a > b then finding a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a_n=.9^n$ and $b_n=.5$  for all $n$, then $.5=b>a=0$ but $a_1>b_1$.